# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task:

Tags: c, ubuntu, docker

Изучаю Docker. Дошел до этой [главы](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/multi-stage/). Для понимания происходящего решил уменьшить размер уже своего образа с помощью многоэтапной сборки. Ничего проще чем вывести в консоль `hello` на языке Си не знаю.

Вот вариант без уменьшения размера образа(одноэтапная сборка).

Написал код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("hello\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Мой Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
COPY start.c .
RUN gcc start.c
ENTRYPOINT ./a.out
```

Собираю образ

`sudo docker build --tag=q1 .`

Сборка проходит успешно.

Запускаю контейнер

`sudo docker run --rm -it q1`

получаю

`hello`

Тут все работает.

Теперь вариант с уменьшением размера образа(двухэтапная сборка).

Мой Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
COPY start.c .
RUN gcc start.c


FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 /a.out /
ENTRYPOINT ./a.out
```

Собираю образ

`sudo docker build --tag=q2 .`

Сборка проходит успешно.

Запускаю контейнер

`sudo docker run --rm -it q2 /bin/sh`

получаю

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

В первом случае как бы понятно что есть все реобходимое учитывая размер образа. Во втором вроде не хватает `/bin/sh`, но как его получить в образе с двухэтапной сборкой неясно.

Вопрос: **Как запустить a.out в контейнере работающем на образе полученном из двухэтапной сборки???**

Comment: Во-первых, `ENTRYPOINT ["/a.out"]`. Во-вторых, всё равно ничего не запустится, потому что в scratch отсутствуют системные библиотеки, необходимые для работы вашей программы

Comment: @andreymal как я могу их добавить? В примере из документации тоже используется `FROM scratch` однако там все работает. Я не знакток Golang но все же почему?

Comment: Именно потому что там Golang, программы на котором могут не зависеть от сторонних библиотек. С сишечкой и многими другими ЯП так уже не прокатит

Comment: Хотя в данном конкретном случае добавление опций `-static -static-libgcc` к компилятору вроде бы делает образ работоспособным. Однако, во-первых, в более сложных программах это может не прокатить, а во-вторых, статическая линковка может иметь юридические последствия из-за условий лицензий (L)GPL (но я не разбирался какие именно)

Comment: @andreymal Да действительно работает) спасибо)) Насчет юридических последствий не совсем понял но надеюсь что-нибудь да нагуглю))